# 500 error vs 404 error which one is more desirable?

Tags: django, ubuntu, server, http-status-code-404

I am a student who is studying the development of django.
I have a question about ***404*** and ***500*** errors.
I handle 404,500 error as 404.html and 500.html respectively.

So, is there a difference between these two error events?

For example,

```py
def example_post_404(request, pk):
    get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk) # code that may occur 404 error

        vs

def example_post_500(request, pk):
    Post.objects.get(id=pk) # code that may occur 500 error
```

Did 500 error event put more pressure on the server than 404 error event?

Which code is more desirable?

*My code is running on AWS EC2 ubuntu-16.04*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between any 400 error versus a 500 error is based on whether it is the fault of the client or the server that the request was not parsed.

for instance, a 404 error means the object was not found; what does this mean? it means that based on what the *client* was asking for, the server could not return a result.

another example, a 503 Service Unavailable; the server recieved the reponse, and although the client request is valid the *server* was unable to provide the response.

That is the difference between a 4XX error and a 5XX error, if you'd like more detailed information on what to respond with when an error occurs, please refer to the HTTP documentation:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

Comment: Thanks! This is what I just want on my question!

Answer (score 2):

404 is [page not found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

500 is [an internal system error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

If a user requested a page/url that does not exist, return 404. If something happens to your system (like a bug, an unexpected error), return 500.

Answer (score 1):

404 Error is Page not found to url calling.

500 is an internal error for our system(like Django  un-authenticate user access)